# 'Promoted' to manager but no pay increase

Tags: management, salary

I have been 'Promoted' to manager but in order for me to achieve my pay raise I have to 'prove myself', as I keep being told. I have ran perfect shifts for weeks now and every time I ask about it i get told I haven't been judged properly. The other manager at my store is on 8.50 and is younger than me, she also did not have to prove herself in order to get the pay raise, it was just given. I am also 5 months pregnant and have to prepare for a baby, doing more work for less money. Is there a law around this or anything I can do???

Comment: Location. Also, do you get paid when you are on maternity leave?

Comment: The 8.50 statement is only useeful when compared to yourself

Answer (score 13):

The way to approach this is to get clarity on the process. Sit down with your bosses and ask them exactly what it means for you to "prove yourself", and how long it will take. I would expect them to give you a definition of what a good shift is, and how long you have to run them to be approved. You should also ask what will happen if you don't prove yourself - will you go back to your old job, or will you be fired? If they give you answers, get them in writing, or at least send an email setting down the answers they gave you so they are recorded.

If they refuse to tell you what it means to prove yourself, I'm afraid that's a red flag that something is going on. It's a double red flag if they intend to fire you if you fail. You might try asking why they promoted you if they didn't think you were able to do the job, but it probably won't help. You might also consider telling them you want to decline the promotion and go back to your old job. If they won't allow that then it's another red flag.

Putting on my cynic's hat for a minute, one thing that might be going on is that if you are in a country where maternity leave is granted, and especially when the employer pays for some of it, this might be a ploy to avoid paying it. They would promote you, put you on probation in your new job, then say you haven't passed the probation and fire you. I don't know they are doing that but it's worth thinking about.

By the way I would not accept a promotion unless I was told what the new pay was going to be, when I would get it, and what I had to do to achieve it. When they promoted you was the time to be asking questions.

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR: Discrimination while giving pay raise can be illegal, check with lawyer**

IMO, The first thing you need to prioritize is your and your to-be-born child's health. No amount of pay raise will justify you working the long hours and putting yourself under undue stress.

Next, while promotions are usually accompanied with pay raises, I did not come across laws that mandate it (with my limited google foo) in any jurisdiction.

Simply stated, a promotion is akin to signing a fresh contract - which expands upon your responsibilities, and may expand your salary and other benefits. However, in the present case, it seems you've already accepted the promotion without a pay raise, with a "verbal" promise of a future pay raise. So there is not much you can negotiate around as the promotion has already happened.

That said, it seems you are going to be on maternity leave in a few months time, and one reason you may not have received the raise could be that your employer may have wanted to save on some of that extra pay they would have to give you during your maternity leave. For example, that is 6 months of law mandated paid leave in India, and extensible by another 1 month + any accumulated leaves with employer consent. By denying a raise right now, they may be buying more time to delay the raise.

However, they did give your female coworker a raise when being promoted to a manger, who is also younger than you.

Thus, this inequitable act on your employer's behalf could be grounds for discrimination against you due to your pregnancy, or age difference (if it is a significant number), and depending on the jurisdiction you are in, can be illegal. So, check with a lawyer in your area and consult if it is really is the case, and then proceed ahead with the course of action the lawyer suggests.

That said, I will again emphasize the need to watch out the hours you work to avoid undue stress.

Comment: Agreed - very much dependent on your location, but if they are treating you differently because of your pregnancy in many jurisdictions that would be illegal.

Comment: @Phueal True that - my point was that just promotion without pay raise is not illegal in itself, however, discrimination can be illegal based on jurisdiction, so OP should contact a lawyer for that. Updating the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me be the next person to congratulate you on your new child.

The whole idea that after being promoted, you have to "prove yourself" before getting the raise that goes with the promotion, is a crock. If there were any *reasonable* doubt that you could perform acceptably as a manager they should never have made you a manager, and if there is no reasonable doubt there is no excuse for withholding the raise.

Most likely they found that they needed a manager, and instead of providing the training required, and testing your ability to handle the things that managers need to handle, they have instead elected to toss you into the role to see if you work out. They did this because it's easy. For them.

As others have said, whether this is legal or not depends on where your company is located. Different places have different laws.

However, what is not in dispute is that you work for people who lack integrity. I recommend that you look for a position with another company during your upcoming maternity leave.

Answer (score 0):

I completely empathize with you and your situation, but there seems to be a lack of clarity on your company's part. What does "judged properly" mean? Is it that you have not been appraised as per the fiscal year? And, although it is a fairly common practice but i would advise you to not compare yourself with any other manager or their salary, and check the increment that you duly deserve if your salary package is less than the market standard in your region with regard to your designation. IN the meanwhile:

- Ask your supervisor for a one-on-one meeting to discuss this issue.
- Ask for a mid-year or early annual evaluation of your performance.
- Finally, based on the ratings of your performance, discuss the increment %.

Hope this helps.
Thanks.